# why mysql_query executes multiple times

Tags: php, mysql, refresh

i have a function and an update query in it like this :

```
//Article Function
function article()
{
    if($_GET['action'] == "article" && !empty($_GET['id']))
    {
        $id = intval($_GET['id']);
        $article = array();
        $selectArticle = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id='$id'");
        $rowArticle = mysql_fetch_array($selectArticle);

        $id = $rowArticle['id'];
        $title = stripcslashes($rowArticle['title']);
        $category = stripcslashes($rowArticle['category']);
        $image = stripcslashes($rowArticle['image']);
        $description = stripcslashes($rowArticle['description']);
        $full_description = stripcslashes($rowArticle['full_description']);
        $keywords = stripcslashes($rowArticle['keywords']);
        $url = "/article/" . $rowArticle['id'] . "/" . str_replace(" ","-",stripcslashes($rowArticle['title']));
        $article = array('id' => $id, 'title' => $title, 'category' => $category, 'image' => $image, 'description' => $description, 'full_description' => $full_description, 'keywords' => $keywords, 'url' => $url);
        mysql_query("UPDATE articles SET visits=visits+1 WHERE id='7'");
    }
    return $article;
}
```

the function called only once but the query runs multiple times when i refresh the page.

for example in first load the **visits** column is 24 and after refresh the **visits** column is 48 !!!!!!

i cant understand why i am mixed up

Comment: Are you sure the article function isn't called more than once? And is the visits column an integer column?

Comment: i called function like this just once -> $article = article();

Comment: How do you check the visits column? The code updates the row with `id = 7` every time, shouldn't it update where `id = $id`?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just adding the number of visits to itself? Run it again - is `visits` now 96?

Comment: no every time i refresh the page 24 adds to visits

Comment: its possible that the the page reload 24 times because of scripts or everything else?

Comment: i write to a file in php file and i find out the page runs 24 times but why?

Comment: Are you talking about the value for visits for id = 7?

Comment: yes i am talking about it in database

Answer (score -1):

1..Use header and redirect the page.

```
   header("Location:your_page.php");
```

2..You can redirect to same page or different page.

```
   Unset $_POST after inserting it to Database.
   unset($_POST);
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: the page loads 24 time but why?

Comment: Sorry I wrote message in wrong window. Can you please let us know the code from where you are calling article() function?

Comment: it is posible that rewrite rules affect this?